# How to get a specific part of a string in java

Tags: java, android, string, datetime, dayofmonth

I'm developing an Android app that gets the date from the internet. What I have is a complete date format like this one :  `2020-06-13T16:21:15.239920+02:00`. I want to get the day of the month (which is **13** in this case).

Comment: You can use String functions to get date based upon character positions or you can use data/time formatter available in java to get the date

Comment: @NitinBisht but how to get it based upon character positions (I'm beginner)

Comment: If you only want it for this format you can use YOUR_STRING.substring(8,10);

Comment: @MohamedHassan check `substring` method

Comment: @Everyone Please don’t use string functions. Use date-time functions like the top-voted answers say.

Comment: If you’ve got two strings `2020-06-13T23:59:01.239920-12:00` and `2020-06-13T00:00:15.239920+14:00`, do you want 13 in both cases? There are almost 50 hours, more than 2 days, between the two points in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using at least API level 26, then you can use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/ZonedDateTime) class as your string uses the default format that is understood by that class.

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-06-13T16:21:15.239920+02:00");
int d = zdt.getDayOfMonth();
```

Alternatively, if the format is constant, simply use method `substring()`

```java
String dd = "2020-06-13T16:21:15.239920+02:00".substring(8, 10);
```

If the format is not constant, I would suggest either [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) or combining `ZonedDateTime` with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter)

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` isn’t necessary. `OffsetDateTime` will do since the string contains an offset, +02:00, not a time zone like Asia/Jerusalem. Otherwise a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your date/time string complies with [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME). You can use `java.time` API to get the day of the month as shown below:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "2020-06-13T16:21:15.239920+02:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr);
        int day = odt.getDayOfMonth();
        System.out.println(day);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
13
```

If you can not use [Java SE 8 Date and Time](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html), check [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and also [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: OffsetDateTime.parse interprets the string in DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME by default.  So, you can simplify for the OP's case by dropping specifying the format and the ZoneOffset and get the same result.

Comment: @jrahhali - Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "2020-06-13T16:21:15.239920+02:00";
String substr = "";

// prints the substring after index 7(8 includes) till index 9(10 excludes)
substr = str.substring(8, 10);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Its always a bad idea to split a string and extract data becuase the string will change to some other value once the date , month or any part of the date string changes and the string indexing will change

So use `DateTimeFormatter`

```
import java.time.MonthDay;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;

public class SDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TemporalAccessor parse = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxx")
                .parse("2020-06-13T16:21:15.239920+02:00");

        int dayOfMonth = MonthDay.from(parse).getDayOfMonth();
        System.out.println(dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a method `getDayOfMonth()` available on this variable

```
private int parseDate(ZonedDateTime date) {
    int day = date.getDayOfMonth();
    return day;
}
```

Comment: The given input `2020-06-13T16:21:15.239920+02:00` is appropriate for `OffsetDateTime` class rather than `ZonedDateTime`. See the [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62361576/642706).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **String split**. Just take this whole format of date and put it into String and then create a **new String Array** `String[] array= str.split("[-T]");` and then you can get result from `array[2]`.

```
String str = "2020-06-13T16:21:15.239920+02:00";
String[] array= str.split("[-T]");

System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + array[2]);
```

**Output:** 13

Comment: While the code in this Answer may work we have a purpose-built class for this: [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=offsetdatetime+java+11&t=osx&ia=web). See the [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62361576/642706).